# undo last change on current line

Tags: undo-redo

I regularly find myself editing some code, encountering an error in a function and then changing the function call and the function itself to debug the problem. Once the problem in the function is solved, I then want to revert the call to what it was. Of course I always forget to save the call to a register beforehand, and I figured the most intuitive solution would be to undo the last change on the current line. I have not been able to find such functionality in Vim however. Is there something I overlooked? In my mind I see a mapping that branches the undo tree and replays all edits, except the last one on the current line.

Comment: see if `U` (uppercase) helps...

Comment: From `:h U`: "Undo all latest changes on one line, the line where the *latest* change was made." I'm specifically not looking to undo the latest change in the file, but the latest change on the line.

Comment: `undotree()` doesn't contain line numbers. Probably the easiest way is to 1) undo all changes back to original state, 2) yank link, 3) put changes back, 4) put. That being said, I personally like to use a version control system (git, hg, svn, whatever) for pretty much everything I do to solve this

Comment: your first option sounds interesting. I do use version control as well, but I find myself not committing for these changes as they seem very small at first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will probably do what you want:

```
function! Undoline()
  let pos = getpos(".")
  let current = getline(pos[1])
  let chg = changenr()
  while changenr() > 0 && current ==# getline(pos[1])
    silent exec 'u'
  endwhile
  let old = getline(pos[1])

  while changenr() < chg
    silent exec 'redo'
  endwhile
  " undo if we jumped over a gap
  if changenr() > chg
    silent exec 'u'
  endif
  call setpos('.', pos)
  if old ==# current
    echo 'no change found'
  else
    call setline(pos[1], old)
  endif
endfunction
```

It will `undo` until the line you are on changes, take the old value, `redo` to your current state and then replace the line with the old value.

It will obviously not work if a line above was added or removed, in that case take a look at one of the [undo browsing plugins](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_undo_branches#Plugins).

Comment: Thanks, this goes a long way. The only problem I have currently is that I can't undo two edits (it just goes back and forth as the undo is considered a change). I'll wait a bit and see if anyone comes up with another solution. By the way, is there a reason you do not use `let current = getline('.')`?

Comment: @Octaviour if you know a bit of vimscript you can modify the function to accept a count argument and then wait until you find `count` undo changes on that line. I used getline that way for consistency (see old).

Comment: Count might be an option. I was thinking more in the direction of keeping track of changnumbers that are introduced because of this function. I think this is a better solution because it does not require you to keep track of the number of changes. I've accepted your solution as I think it solves the initial problem and polishing it is trivial.

Comment: @Octaviour do you have a more polished version you could share?